# How to get integer value from intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

As shown in the below image, I was trying get the two value from the bundle. 
The values can be seen while debugging. First one is `int` and second one is `String`. I can only take the String value. Integer value is being **0** instead of **2**. Any Idea?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is an integer? Because it can be placed inside the bundle as string. In fact you see the bundle debug data as a unique string.
Try instead getting it as string and then parse it or, even better, check the part of code whenre you generate the onActivityResult intent and put it in the bundle as int

Comment: Of cuz.., I didn't notice that. It was a long value.. xD